# TypeError: RFB is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to impement a vnc client with angularJS ([see tutorial here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/08/remote-desktop-vnc-client-with-angularjs-and-yeoman/)), but getting this error when running the application: *TypeError: RFB is not a function*

Here is the server.js code:

```
var RFB = require('rfb2'),
    io = require('socket.io'),
    Png = require('../node_modules/node-png/lib/png').Png,
    express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    clients = [],
    Config = {
      HTTP_PORT: 8090
    };

function createRfbConnection(config, socket) {
  try {
    var r = RFB({
      host: 'config.hostname',
      port: config.port,
      password: config.password,
      securityType: 'vnc',
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  addEventHandlers(r, socket);
  return r;
}

function addEventHandlers(r, socket) {
  var initialized = false,
      screenWidth, screenHeight;

  function handleConnection(width, height) {
    screenWidth = width;
    screenHeight = height;
    console.info('RFB connection established');
    socket.emit('init', {
      width: width,
      height: height
    });
    clients.push({
      socket: socket,
      rfb: r,
      interval: setInterval(function () {
        r.requestRedraw();
      }, 1000)
    });
    r.requestRedraw();
    initialized = true;
  }

  r.on('error', function () {
    console.error('Error while talking with the remote RFB server');
  });

  r.on('raw', function (rect) {
    !initialized && handleConnection(rect.width, rect.height);
    socket.emit('frame', {
      x: rect.x,
      y: rect.y,
      width: rect.width,
      height: rect.height,
      image: encodeFrame(rect).toString('base64')
    });
    r.requestUpdate({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      subscribe: 1,
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeight
    });
  });

  r.on('*', function () {
    console.error(arguments);
  });
}

function encodeFrame(rect) {
  var rgb = new Buffer(rect.width * rect.height * 3, 'binary'),
      offset = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < rect.fb.length; i += 4) {
    rgb[offset++] = rect.fb[i + 2];
    rgb[offset++] = rect.fb[i + 1];
    rgb[offset++] = rect.fb[i];
  }
  var image = new Png(rgb, rect.width, rect.height, 'rgb');
  return image.encodeSync();
}

function disconnectClient(socket) {
  clients.forEach(function (client) {
    if (client.socket === socket) {
      client.rfb.end();
      clearInterval(client.interval);
    }
  });
  clients = clients.filter(function (client) {
    return client.socket === socket;
  });
}

exports.run = function () {
  var app = express(),
      server = http.createServer(app);

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../client/app'));
  server.listen(Config.HTTP_PORT);

  console.log('Listening on port', Config.HTTP_PORT);

  io = io.listen(server, { log: false });
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.info('Client connected');
    socket.on('init', function (config) {
      var r = createRfbConnection(config, socket);
      socket.on('mouse', function (evnt) {
        r.sendPointer(evnt.x, evnt.y, evnt.button);
      });
      socket.on('keyboard', function (evnt) {
        r.sendKey(evnt.keyCode, evnt.isDown);
        console.info('Keyboard input')
      });
      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        disconnectClient(socket);
        console.info('Client disconnected')
      });
    });
  });
};
```

and the error:

```
Listening on port 8090
Client connected
[TypeError: RFB is not a function]
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at addEventHandlers (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\lib\server.js:49:4)
    at createRfbConnection (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\lib\server.js:22:3)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\lib\server.js:114:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.onevent (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (C:\Users\Aqqalu\Desktop\test\VNC\proxy\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:247:12)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: do you have rfb2 installed? `npm install rfb2`

Comment: Yes, i have rfb2 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from a quick glimpse in the docs, it seems to me, that you forgot to call the `createConnection` method on the `rfb` object. It does not seem to be callable as is.

```
var rfb = require('rfb2');
var r = rfb.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5900,
  password: 'secret'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) 
I had some issues while installing npm rfb. So I used Rfb 2 instead.
Can you maybe explain that the difference between these 2 modules are?

Comment: ok. Now I get this message while trying to connect to the vnc server:
Error while talking with the remote RFB server

Comment: No, I don't know anything about Rfb(2), I just make a quick check in Rfb2 readme. Also I don't have any idea why you have problems with connecting to the server. I'd recommend a) checking whether there is some server listening at port 5900 on localhost and then b) trying to connect with some other client

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping me. I've solved the main problem.